# Extract the value in the line after matching pattern

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract the value in a Nth line after the matching pattern `'kappa (ts/tv) ='`. I used the following command using awk.

```
awk '/kappa (ts/tv) =/{print $NF}' text.txt
```

But I am getting an error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: error: Unmatched ( or \(: /kappa (ts/
```

I also get this error with 'sed' also. I know I am missing something here regarding regular expression.

Can anyone give any suggestions?

Comment: You have an unescaped forward slash there: `(ts/tv)`

Comment: Are you looking for literal `(` and `)`?

Comment: Yes I am looking for literal ( and ). Do I need to add any expression before ( and )?

Comment: note that `$NF` doesn't mean Nth line, that's last field's value in every line `awk` currently processing  (where fields are delimited by whitespaces "Tabs/Spaces" by default in `awk`), so apart of the problem your command has and answers below pointed that out, your question it's not clear what are you asking for. please do **[edit]** and clarify (giving a minimum fragmented testable input/output would help much easier to understand your question ).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621326/1745001 for how to ask such a question.

Answer (score 7):

You have two problems there. First, the match operator is using `/` as the delimiter. However, the pattern you are looking for also contains an `/`. This means that this:

```
/kappa (ts/tv) =/
```

Is interpreted as `/kappa (ts/` and then `tv) =/` which gives a syntax error. You need to escape the `/` and make it `\/`. Next, the parentheses have a special meaning in regular expression contexts (in *some* regex flavors, anyway): they are used to capture a matched group. So these also need top be escaped to do what you want. Putting all this together gives:

```
awk '/kappa \(ts\/tv\) =/{print $NF}' text.txt
```

Comment: It may also be worth to mention that the regular expression flavor that Awk uses is [Extended Regex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 errors here: parenthesis and slash should be escaped. All in all, it should be:

```
awk '/kappa \(ts\/tv\) =/ {print $NF}' text.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear enough and my answer is based on your saying:

> *"extract the value in a N<sup>th</sup> line after the matching pattern ..."*

```
awk -v line_num_after_match=1 '
    NR==seen+line_num_after_match && seen { print; seen=0; };
    /kappa \(ts\/tv\) =/ && !seen { seen=NR; }' infile
```

running on the below input:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4: kappa (ts/tv) =
line 5: another kappa (ts/tv) = but line 1 after match
line 6: but line 2 after first match and line 1 after second match
line 7: but line 3 after first match and line 2 after second match
line 8: yet another kappa (ts/tv) =
line 9: xxxxxxxx
```

returns:

```
line 5: another kappa (ts/tv) = but line 1 after match
line 6: but line 2 after first match and line 1 after second match
line 9: xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not mention Nth line, because I am not worried about which line the match string exists only once in the 1000 lines and the 'match string' may be present in any of the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the characters in your search string to be treated literally you should be doing a string comparison instead of a regexp comparison. Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
kappa (ts/tv) =
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

you can use `index()` for a partial string match instead of the partial regexp match you were doing:

```
$ awk -v n=5 'c&&!--c; index($0,"kappa (ts/tv) ="){c=n}' file
8
```

```
$ awk -v n=2 'c&&!--c; index($0,"kappa (ts/tv) ="){c=n}' file
5
```

or use `$0 == "kappa (ts/tv) ="` instead of `index($0,"kappa (ts/tv) =")` if you wanted a full-line match.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105 for more info on how to print a string after a match.

Answer (score 0):

sed command

```
sed -n '/kappa (ts\/tv) =/p' filename
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
l=re.compile(r'kappa \(ts\/tv\) =')
m=open('filename','r')
for h in m:
    if re.search(l,h):
        print h.strip()
```

~

Comment: What about the aspect "**in the Nth line after** the matching pattern"?